# 18.04 LTS losing Ethernet connection

Tags: networking, ethernet, thunderbolt, usb-c

I recently got myself a new Dell XPS 13 9380. I also bought a [Satechi Multi-Port Adapter V2](https://satechi.net/products/type-c-multi-port-adapter-with-ethernet-v2). I use it to connect Ethernet and external monitor (MHL).

When I plug in the Ethernet cable on work, everything works at the beginning. I get IP 10.85.4.157 via DHCP and 10.85.4.1 gateway and 10.85.2.10 plus 8.8.8.8 for DNS. Internal DNS on 10.85.2.10 and global DNS on 8.8.8.8. Everything works ...  for a while.

But after a while (it can be 1 minute or several hours), things stop working. If I unplug the Ehternet cable, wait for a few seconds, and plug it in again, everything starts working again. But it is very annoying to have to unplug/plug numerous times during the day, and being interrupted in the middle of a browsing session is very annoying.

I believe I see two kinds of problems.

**1)** Sometimes it just seems company-DNS stops being used. I can still ping e.g. google.com but not e.g. docker-repo (an internal name). This is a few nslookups from when this situation occurs

```
$ nslookup docker-repo
Server:     127.0.0.53
Address:    127.0.0.53#53

** server can't find docker-repo: SERVFAIL

$ nslookup docker-repo 10.85.2.10
Server:     10.85.2.10
Address:    10.85.2.10#53

Name:   docker-repo.nss.local
Address: 10.85.2.20

$ nslookup google.com
Server:     127.0.0.53
Address:    127.0.0.53#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 172.217.21.142
Name:   google.com
Address: 2a00:1450:400f:809::200e
```

If I unplug/plug the Ethernet cable it works again

```
$ nslookup docker-repo
Server:     127.0.0.53
Address:    127.0.0.53#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   docker-repo.nss.local
Address: 10.85.2.20
```

**2)** This is even worse. Just as often as 1), I get into a situation where nothing net-related works. I cannot ping anything, neither internal nor external, and neither via DNS-name or direct IP-address. I cannot access anything. Unplug/plug Ethernet cable solves it all.

Below, output from a few commands that may be relevant. I have not noticed any change in the output from those commands, between when everything works, when in situation 1) and when in situation 2)

```
$ netstat -r
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
default         _gateway        0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 enx4865ee131675
10.10.10.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 vboxnet0
10.85.4.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 enx4865ee131675
link-local      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 docker0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 docker0

$ ifconfig
docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
    inet6 fe80::42:2eff:fea7:ad08  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 02:42:2e:a7:ad:08  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 11  bytes 1146 (1.1 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enx4865ee131675: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 10.85.4.157  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.85.4.255
    inet6 fe80::be8e:af6:b243:d097  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 48:65:ee:13:16:75  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 168372  bytes 134652097 (134.6 MB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 206692  bytes 170001872 (170.0 MB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
    RX packets 942087  bytes 560583638 (560.5 MB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 942087  bytes 560583638 (560.5 MB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

vboxnet0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 10.10.10.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.10.10.255
    inet6 fe80::800:27ff:fe00:0  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 0a:00:27:00:00:00  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 5146  bytes 900248 (900.2 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Yes, I have VirtualBox and Docker installed. I have tried adding the following to /etc/network/interfaces, but without it helping

```
iface docker0 inet manual
iface vboxnet0 inet manual
```

Please advice on what I can do to make my network stable. Please let me know if you need me to send more information (e.g. command output when in "working", "1)" or "2)")